# Dock icon as a question mark even though the .desktop file valid.

Tags: gnome, xorg, 17.10

Today I have hit a strange problem with Ubuntu 17.10. I installed Sublime Text created the .desktop file which looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime Text
Version=2.0
Comment=Sublime Text Editor
Exec="/usr/bin/sub" %F
MimeType=text/plain;
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=sublime
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Development;Utility;
```

The sublime icons is present:

```
$ sudo find / -iname "sublime.*" 2>/dev/null
/home/thor/tmp/sublime.desktop
/usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/48/apps/sublime.svg
```

and it shows when I search for sublime:

[image]

But when I run it the dock icon is missing.

[image]

I tried pointing to the icon with absolute path in .desktop file - the same result.

Comment: You can try and change the icon pack to another one and see if it appears there

Comment: Thank you @pomsky. Setting StartupWMClass helped. Create an answer so I can accept.